# Purifier and 'appearing as witchcraft user': what happens?

Tags: werewolv.es

Some items make you appear as user of witchcraft, and there is the Spellbound status which has the same effect. If a non-magic role appears as witchcraft user and is targeted by a Purifier, what happens? Does their role get changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a shocking turn of events, the code actually handles this is in a somewhat sensible fashion.

Player modifiers/auras do not effect whether or not the Purifier will purge their target, it is all based off whether their role is classed as WC or not to begin with.